XBRL formulae_cover and complement variations
I would like to understand how "complement", "cover" and "bindAsSequence" work in XBRL formulae.
Do I understand correctly, that:

If a factVariable/generalVariable has "bindAsSequence"=true =>
a) means that elements inside a factVariable will be tested as a group
b) means that generalVariable applies to all factVariables inside the ValueAssertion

If a factVariable/generalVariable has "bindAsSequence"=false =>
a) means that elements inside a factVariable will NOT be tested as a group
b) means that generalVariable DOES NOT apply to all factVariables inside the ValueAssertion

If a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension has "cover"=true and "complement"=true
means a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension will be EXCLUDED from the formula test

If a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension has "cover"=true and "complement"=false
means a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension will be tested in the formula

If a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension has "cover"=false and "complement"=true
means a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension - I don't know, please, help me to understand

If a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension has "cover"=false and "complement"=false
means a conceptName/explicitDimension/typedDimension - I don't know, please, help me to understand


Example for #5

"cover"=false and "complement"=true

Example for #6

"cover"=false and "complement"=false


The general idea is that the XBRL formula machinery groups facts, and then evaluates the formula or assertion within each group.
Facts land into the same group if they have the same aspects (concepts, periods, entities, units, dimensions, etc) except the aspects that are used ("covered") in the filters. For example, for a very simple value assertion that checks that a concept is the sum of some other concepts, the concept aspect is covered and facts are grouped based on all aspects other than the concept.
Within a group, each variable is bound in turn to each fact that passes its filter, i.e., each fact triggers a different evaluation of the formula or assertion. If there are multiple variables with multiple facts passing their filters (all within the same group), then all possible binding combinations are taken.
By default, bindAsSequence is false, cover is true and complement is false. The behavior described above thus corresponds to these default values.
The effect of setting bindAsSequence to true for a filter is that, if there are several facts within the same group that pass the filter, then the variable is bound only once to the entire sequence, leading to less evaluations.
The effect of setting cover for a filter to false is that any use of an aspect in this filter has no effect on the grouping, i.e., facts with different values for that aspect will remain in different groups.
The effect of setting complement for a filter to true is that the filter is inverted: facts that would have passed the filter do not pass the inverted filter, and facts that would not have passed the filter do pass it.

Thank you!
"Facts land into the same group if they have the same aspects (concepts, periods, entities, values, dimensions, etc) except the aspects that are used ("covered") in the filters."
When you say "covered", you mean "cover=true"? But by default, when "cover=true" the same aspects land into the same group.
"... concept aspect is covered and facts are grouped based on all aspects other than the concept."
Did I understand correctly that all aspects other than the concept are [periods, entities, values, dimensions, etc]?

When under the orFilter we have

dimension "CountryAxis" has cover=false and complement=true => dimension is tested outside of the group, what does complement mean here?
dimension "CountryAxis" with member "554" has cover=false and complement=false => dimension is tested in different groups that is equal to "CountryAxis" with member "554"


Yes, covered means cover=true which is the default for the filters. Aspects include concept, entity, period, unit, language, as well as all dimensions (although language is not considered an aspect in the current XBRL formula specification, not sure if this will be fixed in the future). The aspects are basically the dimensions of the data cubes. The fact value is not an aspect and neither are decimals/precision.

complement=true is like a logical not. That is, an orFilter with a complemented country filter on 553 and a non-complemented country filter on 554 corresponds to (country != 553 or country = 554).

I realized there was a typo in my original text in the list of aspects. I fixed it.

I see, thank you! If explicitDimension/conceptName/typedDimension/orFilter/aspectCover has empty cover and complement => how does it affect all factVariables, generalVariables, precondition under the valueAssertion?

Also I would like to understand what does bindAsSequence to generalVariable:

generalVariable has bindAsSequence=true => aspects (concept, entity, period, unit, language, all dimensions) under the factVariables will be tested in the same group?
generalVariable has bindAsSequence=false => aspects (concept, entity, period, unit, language, all dimensions) under the factVariables will be tested in different groups?


I found cases where under the valueAssertion there are 1. four factVariables with conceptName and aspectCover (period, unit, dimensions) cover=true and complement=false; 2. one factVariable with explicitDimensions and aspectCover (unit) cover=true and complement=true => here what does the formula?
